# swap different size range in a vector

Tags: c++

In C++ vector STL library, to s there a function   to swap two range of different size with using another vector?

For example a given vector contains

[1,**2,3**,4,5,**6,7,8,9**]

Expected outcome:
[1,6,7,8,9,4,5,2,3]

Comment: No such standard function exists.  You'll have to write it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no specific function to do this, but multiple uses of [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) should suffice.

The algorithm does this in two steps: first, we move the right-most range over to the left, and then we move whatever was between the right-most range and left-most range to the left of the left-most range. Then, the user programmer just needs to input the correct iterator offsets, which for your example, are

- `1` the leftmost range, starting with '2'
- `3` one-past-the-end of the leftmost range, starting with '4'
- `5` the rightmost range, starting with '6'
- `vector.end()` the end of the rightmost range (could also do `9`, if there were more elements past the '9' in the list)

The code to do this is very simple:

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

template<typename IT>
void swap_ranges(IT start_a, IT end_a, IT start_b, IT end_b) {
    //Will return the position after the moved elements
    auto it = std::rotate(start_a, start_b, end_b);
    //Will determine the point where the new range needs to be moved from
    auto new_start_a = (end_a - start_a) + it;
    std::rotate(it, new_start_a, end_b);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> values{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    std::cout << "Before: {";
    for(int value : values)
        std::cout << value << ',';
    std::cout << "}\n";
    //=========================='2'================='4'================='6'=========='\0'
    swap_ranges(values.begin() + 1, values.begin() + 3, values.begin() + 5, values.end());
    std::cout << "After: {";
    for(int value : values)
        std::cout << value << ',';
    std::cout << "}\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Before: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,}
After: {1,6,7,8,9,4,5,2,3,}
```

Comment: `std::stable_partition`, perhaps?

Comment: @user58697 If you feel this is a case where `stable_partition` would solve the problem, you're welcome to submit an answer demonstrating how.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new vector with your specified content with a series of insert range calls:

```
std::vector<int> vec = { ... };
std::vector<int> newvec;
newvec.insert(newvec.end(), vec.begin() + 0, vec.begin() + 1);
newvec.insert(newvec.end(), vec.begin() + 5, vec.begin() + 9);
newvec.insert(newvec.end(), vec.begin() + 3, vec.begin() + 5);
newvec.insert(newvec.end(), vec.begin() + 1, vec.begin() + 3);
```